# which voltage regulator to use for 12v 2A?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I have looked into using 12v linear voltage regulators, coming down from 16V, i need 2 amps and the regulator is only rated for 1.5A (7812 linear voltage regulator)
i am looking for a solution for getting 2A through the regulator. 
my fan is 1.68A rated at 12V and i'd like a little more than that.

can a buck do it? Other linear voltage regulators rated for more amperage?

Thanks!

Comment: Too much current for a linear regulator.

Comment: yes , my understanding is that it is at the maximum, even with a heatsink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear regulator would waste 8W which is quite a bit, so a buck regulator would be much better.

A buck regulator module based on Xlsemi's [XL4016](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL4016%20datasheet.pdf) would do the job nicely with plenty of margin, you can find inexpensive modules on eBay, Aliexpress etc.

Comment: i appareciate the answer - oging to check it out

Comment: current limit as i understand the datasheets is 10A. this is perfect for this application and several others, Cheers!

Comment: The datasheet shows 6A @12V. 10A is the **switch** current limit at 25°C. If the duty cycle is 50% the output current is then limited to 5A. I think they're probably good for 2,3,4, even 5A with reasonable margin, but one can crank the numbers through including thermal factors and see what the datasheet actually promises.